# What are the requirements for running the cleos commad line eos wallet manager?

Tags: cleos, command-line

What is required to use the cleos command line eos wallet manager? Do I need to install other software before running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [step-by-step guide](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs) found at the developer portal.

In a nutshell:

1. Install Docker
2. `docker pull eosio/eos`
3. `docker run --name eosio \
   --publish 7777:7777 \
   --publish 127.0.0.1:5555:5555 \
   --volume CONTRACTS_DIR:CONTRACTS_DIR \
   --detach \
   eosio/eos \
   /bin/bash -c \
   "keosd --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:5555 & exec nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::producer_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin -d /mnt/dev/data --config-dir /mnt/dev/config --http-server-address=0.0.0.0:7777 --access-control-allow-origin=* --contracts-console --http-validate-host=false --filter-on='*'"`
4. Profit!